# How to force a process to start invisible?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, process, controls

I want to start a PDF viewer as an invisible process, force it into a control, and display it again. But the viewer seems to refuse to start invisible. I have already tried these start parameters:

```
ProcessStartInfo pdfViewerStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ApplikationsName, "\"" + path + "\"");
        pdfViewerStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        pdfViewerStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        pdfViewerStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        pdfViewerStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pdfViewerStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Is there anything I can do to force the viewer to start invisible (maybe Win32 API)?

Comment: Use a PDF viewer control instead. This sounds like an ugly hack.

Comment: It is a requirement over which I have no control...

Comment: *"force it into a control"* - This isn't going to work out (see [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)).

Comment: It already works. The only problem is that the process does not start invisibly. Accordingly, you can see how the app is pushed into the control, and that is something to avoid.

Comment: *"It already works."* - It is a common mistake to make no difference between something that works and something that hasn't failed yet. Your code will find itself in the latter category.

Comment: Well, your confidence in my coding abilities is truly inspiring. But may I inquire, is this display of your own exceptional insights accompanied by any practical assistance, or are we here solely to marvel at the grandeur of your intellect?

Comment: I don't know why you are here. I have laid out the facts. What you are trying to do is not supported. It can be made to work so long as you have **full** control over all involved threads. Clearly, you do not control the thread that owns the window(s) of the external program, and you are using Windows Forms so you aren't in full control over **your** threads either. No combination of skills or coding abilities can make the system suddenly decide to work according to your rules.